# Format File Exception ignored by the try catch block

Tags: c++, qt

I have to load data from an XML file by selecting the file using windows explorer. If i am selecting a different format, other then XML, the catch block should get the exception. But it doesn't and the application fails. Here is the code i've written so far. What i am missing?
I throw the execption in the `readVehicles(QString fileName)` from xml method.

```
    QList<Vehicle> VehicleHelper::readVehicles(QString fileName){

     QList<Vehicle> vehicles;
     Vehicle newVehicle;
     QFile file(fileName);
     QDomDocument document;
     if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        throw FileCannotBeOpenException();
     }
     else{
        if(!document.setContent(&file)){
            throw InvalidXMLContentException();
        }
        file.close();
    }

    QDomElement root = document.firstChildElement();
    QDomNodeList carElements = root.elementsByTagName("Car");
    for(int i = 0; i < carElements.size(); i++){

        QDomNode carNode = carElements.at(i);

        QDomElement carElement = carNode.toElement();
        QString carID = carElement.attribute("ID");

       //if the idNumber is null, generate one
       if(carID.isEmpty()){
            QUuid newId = Vehicle::generateID();
            newVehicle.setVehicleId(newId);
       }
       else {
            QUuid id;
            try{
               id = QUuid::QUuid(carID);
            } catch(QException &ex){
               continue;
        }
        newVehicle.setVehicleId(id);
    }

    //Owner
    //****************************************************************
    QDomElement ownerElement = carNode.firstChildElement("Owner");

    //FirstName
    QDomElement fNameElement = ownerElement.firstChildElement("FirstName");
    QString fName = fNameElement.text();


    //LastName
    QDomElement lNameElement = fNameElement.nextSiblingElement("LastName");
    QString lName = lNameElement.text();



    //Address
    QDomElement addressElement = lNameElement.nextSiblingElement("Address");
    QString address = addressElement.text();

    //append vehicle to the list
    vehicles.append(newVehicle);
  }
}
```

and the try-catch block is in the `on_actionOpen_triggered()` method

```
    void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    if(isModified){
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        QString message = "There are unsaved changes! Do you proceed? ";
        msgBox.setWindowTitle("Save Changes");
        msgBox.setText(message);
        msgBox.addButton("Don't save",QMessageBox::NoRole);
        msgBox.addButton(QMessageBox::Save);
        msgBox.addButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
        int result = msgBox.exec();
        if(result == QMessageBox::Save){
            VehicleHelper::writeVehicles(cars,filename);
            msgBox.close();
        } else {
            QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open file");
            if(!fileName.isEmpty()){
                setFileName(fileName);
                QFile file(fileName);
                try {
                    cars = VehicleHelper::readVehicles(fileName);
                } catch(FileCannotBeOpenException &ex) {
                    QMessageBox msgBox;
                    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
                    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Message!");
                    msgBox.setText("Failed to open file");
                    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
                    msgBox.exec();
                    return;

                } catch(InvalidXMLContentException &ex){
                    QMessageBox msgBox;
                    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
                    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Message!");
                    msgBox.setText("Failed to load data!");
                    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
                    msgBox.exec();
                    return;
                }

                setTakenNumbersList(cars);
                //set data to the table view
                populate(cars);
           }
        }
    } else {
        QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open file");
        if(!fileName.isEmpty()){
            setFileName(fileName);
            QFile file(fileName);
            if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
                cars = VehicleHelper::readVehicles(fileName);
                setTakenNumbersList(cars);
                file.close();

                //set data to the table view
                populate(cars);

                ui->actionAdd->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionBy_name->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionBy_registration_date->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionBy_registration_number->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionBy_revision_date->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionBy_type->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionClear_Search->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionDelete->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionEdit->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionSave->setEnabled(true);
                ui->actionSave_As->setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `open()` returns true if the file was sucessfully opened. Nothing about your code determines if an invalid file format was detected.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I can't figure how to check if the invalid format was detected. Can you help me with some suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Is your intention simply to make sure that only XML files were opened and nothing else?

Comment: Yes. I want to make sure that only the xml file can be opened and if it is selected another format to inform the user by a message box.

Comment: Well I suppose you can simply check if the `QString` returned has the last 4 character `".xml"`.

Comment: It's not working. I get the same error. Debug Error. R6010 - abort has been called.

Comment: What exactly did you change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the last four characters are `".xml"` in the `QString` before sending it to the `QFile`.